# How do I hide these visible paths on my artwork on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, art

[image]

If you look closely, you can see the paths of my art even after saving the artwork to my computer! How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

- Select all the shapes which comprise one of the letters
- Open the **Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > Pathfinder`)
- Hit the **Unite** button on the Panel (top left button)

This will combine all the little pieces into one single shape.

- Repeat for each letter

Then re-save.

If saving for web, for the Anti-Aliasing method, be certain to choose **Art Optimized**.